# escribir en un fichero XML - AJAX - JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

Quiero llevar esos datos que escribo, a un XML para así mas adelante conseguir  llevar los datos de un formulario a un XML.  Si pruebo un console.log  pues me sale como si se creara  los datos, pero no sé cómo llevarlo al archivo

```html
<script>`introducir el código aquí`
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        escribir(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ejercicio.xml", true);
xhttp.send();



function escribir(xml){

    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x;
    newEle = xmlDoc.createElement("Nombre");
    newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("Juanito");
    newEle.appendChild(newText);
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Persona")[0];
    x.appendChild(newEle);
    newEle = xmlDoc.createElement("Apelliddo");
    newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("Perez");
    newEle.appendChild(newText);
    x.appendChild(newEle);

    console.log(x);

}     
</script>
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿Necesitas guardar el archivo en el servidor, o con darte la opción de descargar es suficiente? Salu2!

Comment: El archivo debía estar en el servidor, pero ya lo hice, iba  mal encaminado, debia hacer esa parte con PHP, muchas gracias